# Best way to detect Enter/Return key in cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstextview, nsevent

in my cocoa application i need to check enter/return key. for that i have use below code

```
if ((event.keyCode == 36) || (event.keyCode == 76) || (event.keyCode == 13))
{
// Some code after checking Enter key
}
```

can any one suggest this is correct way or Not ? 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: So, return or enter or W?

Answer (score 4):

Not quite the correct way -- you're confusing key codes with character codes. As Peter Hosey points out in his comment, 13 is the **key** code for the W key.

That is, `if ((event.keyCode == 36) || (event.keyCode == 76))` checks if the **key** code is the Return or Enter key.

If you wanted to check the **character** code, then you could do something like:

```
NSString *chars = event.charactersIgnoringModifiers;
unichar aChar = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];
if (aChar == 13 || aChar == 3)
```

…and you would get the same effect.

Comment: It might be easier to use: unichar aChar = [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0]; instead of the the first two lines of code in case you're not interested in the state of shift or Apple key, etc...

Comment: Good point @Todd -- edited to use charactersIgnoringModifiers instead.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "key code" and "character code"?

Comment: A key code is the physical location of the key on the keyboard. E.g. on a US QWERTY keyboard, the key code for "Y" is 16. On a German QWERTZ keyboard, the Y and Z key are swapped, so the key code 16 is for the "Z" key, and the "Y" key has key code 6. Key codes are useful if you're interested in e.g. the WASD as a replacement for arrow keys. Because E.g. on a French AZERTY keyboard, you want to use ZQSD to get the same physical arrangement. Character codes OTOH are the actual characters printed on the key caps, no matter where they appear physically on the keyboard.